# How to delete u'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' and u'\xa0' from a python list

Tags: python, list

I have been struggling for two days but can not figure it out. Here is my code :

```
def find_name():
    i = 0 
    while i != len(links):
        url = links[i]
        r = requests.get(url)
        html = r.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        for n in soup.find_all('tr'):
            td = n.find('td')
            if td: 
                last_name.append(td.text)
        i = i+1 
    del last_name[0:5]
    return last_name
```

It generates a list of Last names, but there are multiple u'\xa0' and '/ u'\n\n\n\n\n in the list I want them gone. I tried everything I knew. Like removing it by checking each element but that gives me value error list.remove(x): x not in list , I also tried to compare each  element to - u'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' and then add to the list. But it did not work. There are other questions on stackoverflow but they all talk about the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.strip#str.strip) on the text before adding it to the `last_name` list.

```
          if td and td.text.strip(): 
              last_name.append(td.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension and the `strip` method:

```
# Your code
last_name = [name for name in last_name if name.strip()]
return last_name
```